# How to change a view in Liquibase

Tags: liquibase, sql-view

I want to change a view which already exists. Isn't there something like \changeView or \alterView in Liquibase?

I already created a view with createView. I tried to use google and search for alterview or changeview, but without any proper results.

Comment: There is an attribute "createIfExists" on "CREATE VIEW". Look [here](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/create_view.html). Maybe that helps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest approach is to drop the old view and create a new one. Re-creating a view does not affect your data.

Answer (score 13):

There is a `replaceIfExists` attribute on `createView` that will replace an existing view.

http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/create_view.html

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is 6 years ago, but can be util for so today.

Liquibase has an option for `<createView>` which is `replaceIfExists="yourBooleanOpt"`. So you can use:

```
<createView
  viewName="yourViewName"
  replaceIfExists="true">
     yourSqlViewSintax
</createView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of some reasons, I could not change or replace my view using either `<sql>` or `<createView>` tags. So, I created sql file with my view definition, and in my changeset I have included this sql file using `<sqlFile>` tag. This tag has attribute `dbms` and it is required, so, do not forget to write correct one. In this way I have changed/updated my existing view. Hope this helps to someone like me.